# Form with 2 values and are null

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring

I'm trying to upload a file and the form data using ajax. But I'm getting a formData object with null values.
I can log the `fileUpload` object corretly but my formData log is empty.

Can someone explain me what's wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var formData = new FormData();
    $('#fileUpload').change(function () {
        formData.append('file',$('#fileUpload')[0].files[0]);
        console.log($('#fileUpload')[0].files[0]);
    });

    $('#btnSubmit').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        formData.append('data',$('#creationForm')[0]);
        console.log(formData);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '/upload/testCase',
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            success: function (result) {},
            error: function () {}
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

And I want to use them in Spring Controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload/testCase" , method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String uploadTestCase(@RequestParam("data") String data, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file ) {
    //TestCases.upload(file);
    System.out.println(data + file);
    return "";
}
```

Comment: try:   formData.append('file',$('#fileUpload')[0].files[0]  , 'myfle.myExtension' );
look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append

Answer (score 0):

`formData` is not null, you are just **not** inspecting it correctly:

Try this:

```
$('#fileUpload').change(function () {       
    formData.append('uploadedFile',$('#fileUpload')[0].files[0]);

    // inspect each key/value entry
    for (var data of formData.entries()) {
        console.log(data[0] + ', ' + data[1]); 
    }

});
```